# diablo2 window mode using ubuntu script

Tags: command-line, bash, wine, scripts, games

I have Diablo 2 installed on one of my drives which I would like to run in Ubuntu, but I don't want to have to go through Terminal, every time, to start it up. I was trying to create a shell script that would just open it for me when I wanted to play it.

This is what I came up with:

```
#! /bin/bash

wine /media/84964ADD964ACF7C/"Program Files (x86)"/Diablo\ II/Diablo\ II.exe -w
```

When I run it I get a `/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error. What am I doing wrong?

- I have changed the permissions to be 755 and
- I run it through the command line but it will not run

Oh, I forgot to put in my answer, that when I run the command above in the command line it works just fine, but when I run my script it doesn't work

```
Problem solved
Apparently when I had accidentally opened up the script in notepad it added some
extra carriage returns, hence the `^M` error. Deleted all the files associated with
the script and redid it in `geany` and it is working just fine now.
```

Comment: Your path seems wrong. BTW. you can use `"` so you don't have to escape spaces.

Comment: If you could edit your question and add your last comment to your question, it will help people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you check that you have made the file executable

Right click on the script file and select properties. Next click on the permissions tab.

[image]

Comment: I already have done that. That was one of the first things that I had done when creating the file.

Comment: OK, worth a try